# MS Access: Why is it not showing one record per report page?

Tags: sql, ms-access, report

I have a report with a header, body, and (blank) footer. I just want it to show the data corresponding to one record per page.

For example my record source has three rows, for example with Name and Comments.

I have the Name in the header, Comments in the body. For some reason it's trying to put the first two rows' Comments under the first Name header, and then the second page has the third Name with the third Comments.

I just want it to have

Page 1: Header 1 (first row's Name), Body 1 (first row's Comment)

Page 2: Header 2 (second row's Name), Body 2 (second row's Comment)

Page 3: Header 3 (third row's Name), Body 3 (third row's Comment)

and so on.

Why isn't it automatically constraining one row's data per report page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you actually want is to not use the Header or Footer, but instead put the Name and Comment together on the detail--you can expand this section to fit your report fields and format them as you want.  Then in the properties of the detail section on the Format tab set the `Force New Page` property to `After Section`